# How to costumize options and style in Autodesk Forge Viewer Extensions

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I'm using Autodesk forge Section Extension and I see that there are some kind of options and style that I can change. For example when the extension is loaded it expects some options (this code is the Autodesk.Forge/SectionTool.js):

```
    export var SectionTool = function(viewer, options)
{
    var _viewer  = viewer.impl;

    var _names = ["section"];
    ...
    var _tintColor = options.tintColor;
    var _tintIntensity = options.tintIntensity;
    ...
    var _gizmoOffsetRight = isNaN(options.gizmoOffsetRight) ? 200 : options.gizmoOffsetRight;
```

However there is no way of change that values, I try to add an option object when I load the extension:

```
const options = {tintColor: {r: 0, g: 1, b: 0},gizmoOffsetRight:10}
this.section = await this.viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Section',options);
```

But I can't, anything I do at the end options object has the same value: {tintColor:r:1,g:1,b:0},and I dont know where it takes that values etc...

All this is because I dont like the gizmo looking and i'd like to maybe place it in a different position for example.

Any help please :(

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about the difference between Section **extension** and Section **tool**. You are passing the custom options to the extension itself, but the extension does not pass them on to the tool. This is what the extension's `load` method looks like:

```js
proto.load = function() {
    var that = this;
    var viewer = this.viewer;

    this.tool = new SectionTool(viewer, {
        tintColor: { r: 1, g: 1, b: 0 },
        tintIntensity: 0.2
    });

    viewer.toolController.registerTool(this.tool, this.setActive.bind(this));
    this.sectionStyle = null;
    this.supportedStyles = ["X", "Y", "Z", "BOX"];
    // ...
}
```

As you can see, the tool options were not meant to be publicly accessible. You *could* try and hack it, though, by overriding the extension's `tool` property after it's been loaded. You'd probably also need to deregister the original `SectionTool` instance, and register the new one.