# Forge viewer auto-play Fusion animation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I need some help to set up the AnimationExtension using custom options to play automatically the animation as soon the model is loaded on the viewer.

So far I loaded the *Autodesk.Fusion360.Animation* extension and set the viewable to the Fusion animation one (through its id, found in the manifest). If I try to play the extension from the console I can get the Autodesk.Fusion360.Animation extension and in the callback using play() or activate(); but if I try to do that from the code it's not working.
Here is my code:

```html
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, (x) => {
  viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Fusion360.Animation').then((y)=> {
    y.options.startOnInitialize=true;
    y.activate();
    y.play();
  })
});
```

From the options I see there is the *startOnInitialize* property, but maybe I can't set the options to the builtin extension: I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65846452/how-to-costumize-options-and-style-in-autodesk-forge-viewer-extensions) about the options in the extensions and the tools...but I don't understand how to apply it in the code, in relation to a basic viewer.

Can you please give me info or a snippet to autoplay a Fusion animation in the viewer and set additional options to the extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Configure the Viewer with the `Autodesk.Fusion360.Animation` extension
   enabled from the beginning.
2. Add a listener to the event `Autodesk.Viewing.ANIMATION_READY_EVENT` to the viewer.
3. When event arrives, play the animation.

Comment: I already tried to load the extension from the beginning, that event makes the difference! Thanks,it works fine now